# Can Flink output be sinked to a NFS or GPFS file system?

Tags: apache-flink, nfs, ext4, distributed-filesystem

Flink has a RollingFileSink which per the documentation works with HDFS (Hadoop).  Are there similar classes which can be used to sink data to file systems such as NFS, ext4 or GPFS?

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html

Comment: Do you use flink distributed / multiple machines? If you are, using a non distributed filesystem might not be your best option.

Comment: Yes, I do.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RollingSink class works with all [Hadoop-compatible file systems](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HCFS) (it simply uses Hadoop's FileSystem abstraction).

The list of compatible file systems includes POSIX-compliant file systems (file://, which covers NFS, ext4, ...) and [GPFS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STXKQY_4.1.1/com.ibm.spectrum.scale.v4r11.adv.doc/bl1adv_hadoop.htm) as well.